# OpenVAS scan not working - Kali linux

Tags: linux, security, openvas

Currently having an issue with my kali VM.
I installed Openvas, but when I try and initiate a scan with the admin user I get the following error message:

Operation:  Run Wizard
Status Code:  400
Status message: Service temporarily down

Has any one experienced this before? Searched online and couldn't really find any solutions.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you started the OpenVAS service on your machine? Kali does not start most services by default; you have to manually start them with `service start`. Can you post a screenshot of the error you are seeing?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. The error message I am seeing is: login failed for user. When I try logging in, the web page redirects to https://172.x.x.x:9392/omp. I done a openvas-check-setup and it reports that the Openvas-8 installation is OK.

Comment: I also did start the services

Comment: Check logs in `/var/log/openvas/`.

Answer (score 1):

I used the Virtual Appliance (Virtual Machine), getting error 400 first and later 503 with "Service temporarily down" when trying to scan.

Solution that worked was found at http://openvas-discuss.wald.intevation.narkive.com/TTK5H8YI/openvas-8-virtual-appliance-unable-to-start-task and can be found at http://plugins.openvas.org/ova_503.txt .

It comes down to stopping services, rebuilding the certificates, updating config and then restarting services. It is a 12 steps process that takes several minutes (maybe 30). I will not copy/paste, the [second link above](http://plugins.openvas.org/ova_503.txt) contains all the steps.

Comment: Thank you, this resolved the issue with my Greenbone installation.